# Cantor diagonal argument; related number

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I was reading another question on mse about cantors proof and I'm curious about a number that could be defined from it. Well there could be a whole heap of them, but one for now.

Define $A=\Bbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$. $A $ is countable so it can be enumerated. Do so as follows $A=\{\frac 12, \frac 13, \frac 23, \frac 14 , \frac 34,  \ldots\}=\{a_1, a_2,\ldots \}$. I don't know a slick formula for the terms in this sequence. Now suppose we write the sequence as a list in decimal form with the convention of using recurring zeros rather than recurring nines for fractions which are multiples of $2$ or $5$:

$\frac 12 =0.50000000\ldots$

$\frac 13 =0.33333333\ldots$

$\frac 23=0.66666666\ldots$

$\vdots$

Now let $a_{m, n}$ be the $n$'th digit of the decimal expansion (not including the whole number part) of $a_m$. Define $b_i=a_{i, i}$ and $b= \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{b_i}{10^i}$.

I would assume based on nothing concrete at all, that $b$ is irrational but I have no idea on how to go about that.

Comment: It's a kind of slap in the face to Cantor's diagonal argument! I expect you are right, and it is irrational; but I can't see a way to prove it either.

Comment: I found a way to prove it $-$ see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a neat question.

The key seems to me to be that you will have recurring decimals e.g. $\frac 19, \frac 1{90}, \frac 1{900}\dots$  infinitely often (note these have non-zero digits in the recurring part, and give non-zero values for the relevant places beyond $9, 90, 900 \dots$.

You will also have $\frac 12, \frac 14, \frac 34, \frac 18, \frac 38, \frac 58, \frac 78 \dots$ which will give arbitrarily long sequences of zeros.

Those two facts mean that you can't have a recurring decimal, or a terminating decimal, so the number you have defined will not be rational (rationals terminate or recur).

Comment: It took me a second reading to realise what you said. That's great thanks!

Comment: Why can't you have a recurring decimal? If I'm allowed to choose my own enumeration of the rationals, perhaps I can choose it so that the diagonalisation results in a recurring sequence. At least, it's not immediately obvious that this is impossible.

Comment: In fact, it is impossible $-$ see my answer.

Comment: @TonyK I was working with the specific enumeration given in the question, and answering the question as given.

Comment: @MarkBennet: But you haven't used any properties of that enumeration, as far as I can see.

Comment: @TonyK I have used the fact that the odd multiples of $\frac 1{2^n}$ come together and give a string of zeros of length $2^{n-1}$

Comment: That is not a property of the enumeration given by the OP. You would have to analyse where such elements occur in the enumeration, and how many non-zero digits they start with. You might be able to make this work eventually, but it would be a lot more work than my diagonal argument!

Comment: @TonyK It is a property of the enumeration given - which is in order of increasing denominators, and with constant denominator, in order of increasing numerators relatively prime to the denominator.

Comment: But you haven't proved anything! You're really just saying that you could if you wanted. And even then, why bother? There's a much easier proof available.

Comment: @TonyK I agree I have not filled out the details of the proof, but I have given enough detail to show how the proof could be completed. What I was trying to do was to answer the question, not to compete with your ideas.

Comment: I still don't think you have answered the question, even in outline. You have left out the hard parts.

Comment: @TonyK I have explained how to show that the decimal expansion can neither recur not terminate - that is sufficient to show it is not rational.

Comment: No you haven't! For instance, you haven't shown that the odd multiples of $\frac{1}{2^n}$ don't occur periodically in the enumeration. If they were periodic, they could coincide with the zeroes of a recurring decimal. Maybe you could show this if you wanted, but you haven't done it. It's certainly not something you can just assume. And even that's not enough, because there could be other elements that happen to have a zero just where it is required to maintain periodicity.

Comment: @TonyK They all have the same denominator, so of course they occur together

Comment: @TonyK I like your solution. I have voted for it. Mine applies to the specific order given in the question, which identifies a specific number. This number is not rational - my observations show that to be true. Your solution shows that no order can give a rational number. I understand what you have written. I will leave my notes here, and leave it for others to judge whether they are sufficient or not.

Comment: @tonyk basically what he's pointed out is that the fractions with denominator $2^n $ all occur next to each other. They always contribute a zero because the number of non zero decimals in 1/2^n increases with $n $ but their positions in the sequence are much slower than that. These grow to arbitrary length, consider $\phi(2^n)$. If the number is rational it must terminate but he s showed there's an infinite number of $1$'s in the expansion so it's not rational. Correct me if I've interpreted it wrong

Comment: You have to show (or at least mention) that the $000\ldots$ part of these terminating decimals starts early enough for the zeroes to be included in the diagonal. Then you have to show that the diagonal can't all be zeroes, by showing that the $111\ldots$ part of those non-terminating decimals starts early enough for the ones to be included in the diagonal. But this seems to be the case. So I retract my objections. Sorry for the fuss.

Comment: @TonyK Thanks for taking the time - I agree those points do have to be nailed down and that they aren't immediately obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the diagonalised number $d = 0.536\ldots$ is rational. Then $d + 0.333\ldots = d + \frac13$ is also a rational number in $(0,1)$. But $d + 0.333\ldots$ differs from $d$ in every decimal place, so it can't occur in your list $-$ a contradiction.

Comment: Tony - I have sketched a proof that the construction does not yield a rational number. You assert the same.

Comment: @Mark: But your proof is deficient. I can construct an infinite sequence of rationals for which the diagonalisation is a recurring sequence. Your answer doesn't show why this sequence can't contain all rationals in $(0,1)$.

Comment: Tony - your proof generalises the result. The question gives a specific ordering of the rationals.

Comment: Just to inteject, $1/9$ and $1/3$  differ in every decimal and they're both rational. Replace $1/9 $ and $1/3$ in your proof and notice that $2/9=1/3$. I don't think this argument works, at least the way I've read it

Comment: @snulty: I don't really understand your comment, but I would like to make two points: 1. I deliberately didn't use $\frac19 = 0.111\ldots$, because carry-digits would wreck my argument; 2. as a matter of fact, $\frac29$ is not equal to $\frac13$.

Comment: Maybe I meant sixths? I'm not sure. Basically I don't follow your proof. Are you saying that because two rationals differ in every decimal place that they can't both be rational?

Comment: What do you mean about carry digits? I am trying to follow this.  Also I do feel very silly about $2/9=1/3$...

Comment: @tonyk I understand what you're saying now but surely if any digit $geq 7 $ is in the decimal expansion of $d$ there's a problem?

Comment: @snulty: no, because that digit will change to $0,1,2,$ or $3$, none of which if $\ge 7$.

Comment: Like the idea is that if $d+1/3$ is rational it's in the list and so agrees with $d$ at at least one digit. It's how $d$ is defined. I'm following so far. Is digits carrying on a problem? Unless you choose a rational such that $d+p/q> 1$ ? I'm definitely missing something

Comment: Carry can only change the result by $1$, and $1 < 3$, so the result will differ from $d$ in all cases. And $d$ is fixed, so $d + \frac13 \approx 0.869 < 1$.

Comment: I appreciate the patience. Like I'm not sure of the significance of choosing $1/3$. I mean I get that you want to choose a fraction which changes every decimal place. That makes sense. But surely no matter what fraction you chose  less than $1-d $ which had no zeros would be fine?

Comment: @snulty: You're probably right $-$ if it has no zeroes _and no nines_. Like, for instance, $1/3$ :-)

Comment: Oh Yeh I forgot the nines!